# Impossible to change server - Failed to download repository information

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, repository

No APT commands are working for me.

According to some posts on this site, the solution would be to change my server. So I tried to change it in settings/software and choose the best server.

However, after downloading cache and other stuffs, I have this error message

```
Failed to download repository information. Check your Internet connection.
```

But my connection is fine. In *details* I have:

```
W:Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:2,
W:Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:2,
W:GPG error: htps://repo.skype.com /deb stable InRelease:
 The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3,
W:The repository 'htps://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W:An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error: htp://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release:
 The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1496576244, 
W:The repository 'htp://ppa.launchpad.net/cdekter/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W:Failed to fetch htp://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1496576244,
E:Failed to fetch http://ubnt-archive.xfree.com.ar/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en.xz  Hash Sum mismatch, 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cdekter/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please specify your OS.

Answer (score 1):

Your repositories seem to be quite a mess. No wonder APT is not working. I am not sure how good you kept track of all your non-standard repositories and PPAs, but your are missing most of the certificates, so the system cannot work.

I guess you are aware that the `apt update` command is laying the base for `apt upgrade` and `apt install` to work. `apt update` is comparing your system state to that of the repositories and updates your local repository information before downloading any installation files.

This works with the configuration files in

```
 etc/apt/...
```

with the main file being

```
 etc/apt/sources.list
```

You have an optional directory

```
 etc/apt/sources.list.d/..
```

that seems to be quite messed up.

My recommendation would be to make a backup of that directory, then delete the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder and replace the original `sources.list` (you surely made a backup? If not see [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) or get the `/etc/apt/sources.list` from an Ubuntu installation disk and copy it onto your installed system). Then try again.

After fixing your repositories the process

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install <whatever you want>
```

should work again.

If so I would recommend to include your alternative repositories into the `sources.list` file and step by step and check with apt upgrade if there is anything missing. The keys you might still have for your PPA can be copied into the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` directory.

Comment: Hello Catman! 

Thank you very much for the answer!
My version of Ubuntu is lts 16.04

I didn't do any backup and don't have the installation cd, is it possible to get the files online ? 

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, just download the installation pack from the ubuntu web site and either make a bootable USB stick or burn a DVD.